# Can't get an image in a table cell to repeat

Tags: html, html-table

I'm working on an e-newsletter with in-line HTML. So far, everything is going fine, except one image will not repeat in its table cell. I've got working "repeat-y" images throughout the rest of the newsletter, but this one cell is not behaving. Any suggestions?

Here's the code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dally/8SEp5/1/)

```
     <table style="width:780px;">  
<tr>

<td style="width: 55px; background: #fffff url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/40e5aa33eb561f0148b1711a92d65043/tumblr_mpk3j3FRaa1snsew1o6_r1_100.jpg) left repeat-y;" valign="top">
    <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/40e5aa33eb561f0148b1711a92d65043/tumblr_mpk3j3FRaa1snsew1o6_r1_100.jpg" width="55" />
    </td>


<td style="background: #ffffff;" valign="top">
    <p style="text-align: right;">
        <span style="font-size:11px;"><span style="color: rgb(126, 146, 175);"><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', helvetica, sans-serif;">texttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br />
</td>
</tr>      
</table>
```

*Edit: The final newsletter will be sent through iContact.com, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css should separate out the background declarations.

Note, I am using the `background`, `background-image`, and `background-repeat` declarations here:

```
<td style="width: 55px; background: #fffff; background-image:url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/40e5aa33eb561f0148b1711a92d65043/tumblr_mpk3j3FRaa1snsew1o6_r1_100.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-y" valign="top">
```

You could also just separate out the background color declaration from the image/repeat declaration and use the same background tag like this:

```
<td style="width: 55px; background: #fffff; background: url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/40e5aa33eb561f0148b1711a92d65043/tumblr_mpk3j3FRaa1snsew1o6_r1_100.jpg) repeat-y;" valign="top">
```

After the repeat is corrected, you should be able to remove the other call to display the image:

```
<table style="width:780px;">  
<tr>
<td style="width: 55px; background: #fffff; background-image:url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/40e5aa33eb561f0148b1711a92d65043/tumblr_mpk3j3FRaa1snsew1o6_r1_100.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-y" valign="top">
</td>   
<td style="background: #ffffff;" valign="top">
    <p style="text-align: right;">
        <span style="font-size:11px;"><span style="color: rgb(126, 146, 175);"><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', helvetica, sans-serif;">texttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br /> texttexttexttexttexttexttext<br />
        </span></span></span>
    </p>
</td>
</tr>      
</table>
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8SEp5/2/).

Edit: Note that you should be [closing](http://jsfiddle.net/8SEp5/3/) the tags you start to create valid HTML.

Comment: This seems to work just fine... 
However, when I apply this back into my newsletter code (which is being hosted through iContact.com), it still won't repeat. Also, if I apply "background-image:" to other backgrounds, it breaks the ones that do work. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: @Dally It might seem like trivial things to check - but make sure your declarations are separated by semicolons, and that you are closing the HTML tags that you are opening.

Comment: I pasted "; background-image:" between all instances of "#ffffff" and "url(" in the document, and doublechecked to make sure all brackets were closed, but it still appears to be broken. I'm thinking it might be the iContact site not accepting "background-image", but this is my first dealing with this site, so I can't know for sure.